# Unity 5 How to open game without configuration screen

Tags: c#, splash-screen, unity-game-engine

when you double-click a Unity file, you are greeted with this image:

[image]

But in (for example) Unturned, the actual game window opens automatically.
Any way to make my game like that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the configuration window or resolution dialog which is not the splash screen.

File->BuildSettings->Resolution and Presentation -> Display Resolution Dialog -> Disabled

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html there is a -show-screen-selector but not sure it is right.